# Regex to find lines containing only integers in vim

Tags: command-line, vim, regex

I have a file containing integers (line numbers) and text.
By extracting a PDF-file those line numbers got put into seperate lines from the text and I want to delete all those line numbers. I'm not very skilled with regexes but I'm 100% sure that it shouldn't be super hard. I use vim/nvim, but if I had to use awk/sed that would work for me, too.

File looks something like this:

```
123
124
125

Text was found in
those three lines
should stay
```

So ideally I want to search for:
all lines, that start with a positive integer (1,2,3...123456) and contain nothing but that integer. They should be deleted.

Any help is much appreciated.

*Bonus challenge*: for some reason, some lines start with `^L1234`, so there's an additional special character. At some point I'd want to delete these as well. Can be separate steps though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `[0-9]` is a simple *collection* of digits that works almost anywhere. In Vim, you can also use `\d` (decimal digit), too.
- You want one or more instances: append the `\+` multiplier.
- That should be the only stuff in the line, so the regexp needs to be *anchored* to the beginning and end (via `^` and `$`, respectively).
- You want to attempt a match on all lines; in Vim, that's done via `:global/{pattern}/`.
- Matching lines should be `:delete`d.

Taken together:

```
:global/^[0-9]\+$/delete
```

You can also use `sed`; it's faster and works non-interactively. As this automatically applies any rule to all input lines, you don't need the `:global`, and the `:delete` is just a `d` there. With `-i`, the replacement is done in place (so be sure to have it right and have a backup copy of the original file!)

```
sed -i -e '/^[0-9]\+$/d' file
```

For the optional prefix, the multiplier for that is `\?`. If that `^L` is a single character, you probably need to enter it in Vim as `<C-V><C-L>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually was closer than I thought. Escaping the `+` character helped a lot, and from there on, I might have guessed the missing `$` sign myself. The `<C-V><C-L>` thing worked just as fine.

Comment: As you can see, there are subtle differences between regexp dialects, not just between Vim and sed. In Vim, you can even influence the amount of escaping (via `\V` / `\v`). You don't need to guess with Vim; it has excellent help. `:help patterns` would have been a good start here.

Answer (score 0):

## Remove lines starting and containing only integers in Vim

```
:%s/^[0-9]\+\n//gc
```

### Explanation

- `:%s//` - global search and replace
- `^` - start at beginning of line
- `[0-9]` - match digits
- `\+` - greedy match one or more
- `\n` match newline (Note: check your line endings, these vary between systems and may be eg `\r\n` instead)
- `gc` - global match + confirm (remove `c` if there's lots or you're sure

### Output

```
123
124
125

Text was found in
those three lines
should stay
```

`:%s/^[0-9]*\n//g`

```
Text was found in
those three lines
should stay
```

### Bonus

Per [terdon's answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219444), the `^L` is the `form feed character`, wih can be removed using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\o14//g' file
```

It is worth reading that answer to see other ways of doing so.